# Querying Django model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I can query the user's profile using the user_id in the UserProfile model below. But I would like to use the username in the `django.contrib.auth.models.User.username` in the urls instead.

The urls.py currently looks like:

```
path('profile/<int:user_id>', login_required(views.UserProfileDetail), name='userprofile'),
```

So as against the above urls, I would like to use something like:

```
path('profile/<str:username>', login_required(views.UserProfileDetail), name='userprofile'),
```

Any idea how to write the query correctly? All attempts so far returns an error

views.py:

```
def UserProfileDetail(request, user_id, *args, **kwargs):

profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = user_id)

profile_display =  {'profiledetail': profile }
return render(request, 'main/userprofile.html', context=profile_display)
```

this is what the model looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile')
    userPhone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept both a `user_id` and a `username` with a default value, and then query with `Q` objects to look for a `UserProfile` where at least one of the two matches. The paths guarantee that one is passed:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required
def UserProfileDetail(request, user_id=None, username=None):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(
        Q(user_id=user_id) | Q(user__username=username)
    )
    profile_display =  {'profiledetail': profile }
    return render(request, 'main/userprofile.html', context=profile_display)
```

You might want to use `login_required` as a decorator instead. This avoids wrapping the view each time in a `login_required`.

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `user_profile_detail`, not <s>`UserProfileDetail`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).